# Strange Delegate Protocol Declaration error?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, avaudioplayer

So in a header file I have the following code:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
@interface alertController:UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
{
  AVAudioPlayer *player;
}
```

I have both the framework linked and It works just fine in another file within the same project, but I am getting the error that it cannot find the protocol declaration for "AVAudioPlayerDelegate", nor does it recognize the line `AVAudioPlayer * audioPlayer` because it is an `unknown type name`.  Any ideas why this isn't working despite my import statement, including the framework, and the fact that it's working fine in another file?

Answer (score 3):

`AVAudioPlayer` (and its delegate) come from AVFoundation, not AudioToolbox. Your other project probably imports `<AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>` either through a separate included header file or through your PCH. You should replace that `#import` with

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```